# Oracle exceptions displayed as PHP warnings not errors

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I'm interacting with an Oracle database using the oci8 interface.

My problem is that whenever the Oracle code raises an exception with an appropriate message and code, PHP emits a warning and not an error.

I need access to the error code, but oci_error always returns false (presumably because it is a warning not an error).

Is there any way to cause these warnings to be shown as errors and correctly populate the call to oci_error?

Comment: From what I see at the oci_error() documentation page, it should work as you expect. Have you tried a single php file to test the warning behaviour? maybe you have an error trigger which raises the warning?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Oracle, but for 'built in' warnings such as expired password, this does work as you say. The error function returns the array correctly. But for our code which raises exceptions, the error function returns false.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was using the API incorrectly, when calling oci_error, you have to pass in the statement resource. This resulted in getting the correct error information.